# combine media query selectors for tablet and mobile into one

Tags: css

Can I combine the following media queries into 1 for what we use for tablets and mobile devices:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 702px) and (max-width: 1040px) {
    .ipad-iframe-container .resize {
        overflow: scroll;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 701px) {
    .ipad-iframe-container .resize {
        overflow: scroll;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }    
}
```

Comment: `@media only screen and (max-width: 1040px)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes?

Everything is the same, except for the width. One style for 701px and below, and the other one is for 702px to 1040px. So effectively, you could just change the rule to 1040px and below.

I assume that any hypothetical sub-pixel screensizes between 701 and 702 are also allowed to use this rule. ;)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1040px) {
    .ipad-iframe-container .resize {
        overflow: scroll;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd say so.  It doesn't matter what the min-width is, they both fall under the remit of the max width of the first media query.